# Finding a harmonic function given some details

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

The function $\Phi$ is defined to be a real valued function of two variables. On the lines $y=-x+3$ and $y=-x-3$ it attains the values as shown on the picture I added. I am a currently self-teaching complex analysis, and I have seen some approaches for solving these problems involving mappings, however, this exercise is to be solved not using those techniques as it is posed before that chapter. What is a general way for solving these(if there is one)?

Comment: For data like these, you take a real-linear function. Once you know that it shall be real-linear, it's not hard to find $\Phi$. Are you asking about something more general, or only harmonic functions on a strip with boundary values that are constant on each bounding line of the strip?

Comment: @DanielFischer am specifically interested in harmonic functions.

Comment: Yes, but are you interested only in parallel strips, or in more general domains? What types of boundary values are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. To answer it, no, circular regions are also of interest, regions made up of one quadrant, regions bounded by two straight lines intersecting at such and such an angle, etc. Nothing too messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Look at it in this way. Rotate the picture $45^o$ clockwise around the origin:
$$
x' = (x+y)/\sqrt{2} \quad ; \quad y' = (x-y)/\sqrt{2}
$$
(Where one might ask *why* the Laplace equation is invariant for rotations)
Then the Laplace problem becomes essentially one-dimensional.
And the boundaries conditions become respectively:
$$
x' = (x+y)/\sqrt{2} = \pm 3/\sqrt{2}
$$
The equation itself is, in the new $(x',y')$ coordinates:
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{d(x')^2} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \phi(x',y') = C x' + D
$$
That is: linear. With boundary conditions:
$$
\phi(-3/\sqrt{2}) = -50 \quad ; \quad \phi(+3/\sqrt{2}) = +10
$$
Consequently:
$$
-50 = C(-3/\sqrt{2}) + D \quad ; \quad +10 = C(+3/\sqrt{2}) + D
$$
When solving for $C$ and $D$:
$$
60 = C\, 6/\sqrt{2} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad C = 10\sqrt{2}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad D = -20
$$
Now rotate the solution back $45^o$ counterclockwise, giving:
$$
\phi(x,y) = 10\sqrt{2}(x+y)/\sqrt{2} - 20 = 10(x+y) - 20
$$
Which is the desired solution.

One can think of a shortcut, once you've got the idea.
Linearity:
$$
\phi(x+y) = (x+y)A+B
$$
Boundary conditions:
$$
\phi(x+y=-3) = -50 \quad ; \quad \phi(x+y=+3) = +10
$$
Giving:
$$
\left. \begin{matrix} -3A+B = -50 \\ +3A+B = +10 \end{matrix} \right\}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{matrix} A = 10 \\ B = -20 \end{matrix} \right.
$$

LATE EDIT. Proof that the Laplace operator is invariant for rotations in the plane.
$$
x_1 = \cos(\theta)\,x - \sin(\theta)\,y \\
y_1 = \sin(\theta)\,x + \cos(\theta)\,y
$$
Chain rules:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}
+ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} = 
\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}
+ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} = 
-\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}
$$
Take squares:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = 
\left[\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}\right]^2
= \cos^2(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}
+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1 \partial y_1}+
\sin^2(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_1^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = 
\left[-\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}\right]^2
= \sin^2(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}
-2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1 \partial y_1}+
\cos^2(\theta)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_1^2}
$$
Add together:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} =
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_1^2}
$$

Comment: About the fact that the Laplace equation is invariant to rotations. I believe it has to  do with the fact that when you differentiate twice $\cos x$ you get $-  \cos x$

Comment: @Shemafied: Not quite, I think. See my LATE EDIT.